# Checkbox having an issue with jQuery Event Binding for Textarea

Tags: html, internet-explorer, google-chrome, jquery

I have an issue with jQuery event binding for Textarea and that causes that checkbox check is not working.

```
//jQuery Part
jQuery("#content").on("click change keypress", "textarea", function(e){
   ...
}
```

and HTML Part

```
<p>
    <textarea name="ele[6a]" id="txt_6a" style="height: 17px; -ms-overflow-x: auto; -ms-overflow-y: hidden; max-height: 17px; box-sizing: border-box;" cols="100">Test</textarea>
    <input name="ele" class="file" id="ele" onchange="myUpload(this,id);" type="file" size="40">
    <input name="ele[6a87]" class="checkbox" id="p6a" type="checkbox" value="1">
</p>
```

Now, when I place above `<p>` element ***outside*** of `#content` DIV then checkbox is working but under that `#content` DIV it's not working.

Any idea about it?

**Note**

This issue is occurred in both `IE*` and `Chrome` as well

Comment: So the event handler that clearly targets `#content` as the parent element for the delegation works fine when the element is not inside that parent, but doesn't work when the element **is** inside the element given in the event handler? Are you sure your markup is valid ?

Comment: @adeneo, Yes. It only doesn't work when element is inside `#content`

Comment: @billyonecan, Thanks for pointing out. I have updated it.